# Java count while index on each other

Tags: java

I want to count `int index = 1;`. I want it to be added up on each other. For example: 1 + 2 + 3 etc. How can i do this? I've already tried this:

```
public void countOneToTen() {
        int index = 1;
        while(index <= 10) {
            index = index + index;
        }
        System.out.println(index);
    }
```

Comment: What is the output you get vs expect?

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 10).sum()` ;)

Comment: The output we get is 15 and we expect is 55. @mango, we cannot use IntStream as this is an assignment of school and they want us to do it this way.. :(

Comment: [`sum (1 ... n) = n * (n + 1) / 2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decouple your "sum" variable and your index variable.

Introduce another variable to hold the sum:

```
public void countOneToTen() {
    int sum = 0;
    int index = 1;
    while (index <= 10) {
        sum += index;
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Also, use for loops to limit variable scope:

```
public void countOneToTen() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 1; index <= 10; index++) {
        sum += index;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Your approach didn't work because your index *should* go from `1` to `10`, but the moment you modify it you throw this iteration off course.

Here's what I mean:

```
index =                 1
// index: 1
index = index + index = 2
// index: 2
index = index + index = 4
// We've skipped 3.
// etc.
index = index + index = 8
index = index + index = 16 > 10

1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15
```

Just for fun, here's the Java 8 stream approach:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).sum();
```

(thanks to Oleg for pointing out the existence of `rangeClosed`)

:)

and here's the single-statement approach using the general [summation of an arithmetic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum):

[image]

```
int sum = terms * (min + max) / 2;
```

Comment: IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).sum() wouldn't look bad either :)

Comment: @Oleg thanks! Was too used to open ranges and didn't check for this

Comment: Thank you for this. Thanks for the great explaining :) It worked!

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a new variable to store your current `sum`.

```
public void countOneToTen() {
        int index = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        while(index <= 10) {
            sum += index;
            ++index;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

or you could use Gauss' trick. let `n = 10` then the sum from `1` to `n` is `n*(n+1)/2`

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
        sum += i;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work. We get the answer 15 in stead of 55.

Comment: You need an extra `sum` variable

Comment: What is Stackoverflow for then? I'm stuck with a question that i need answered. I thought Stackoverflow is a website where you can ask questions. I'm not using Stackoverflow to make my homework, i'm using it to get better in programming. Also, i want to give a clearer question but programming for beginners can be a bit confusing. You've all been there, right?

Comment: 'I'm stuck with a question that i need answered' Basically 10 seconds into googling and you find the answer. Think for yourself before you ask others for help.

Comment: Think for yourself before asking others for help? I've used Google and i couldn't find the answer because i'm new to programming and finding problems can be a bit difficult because i don't know how to describe my programming problem. I'm sorry for using Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Michael The community isn't anti-homework questions, it's just anti-low-quality questions. I think everyone here should read this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823). I don't see anything currently wrong with the question.

Comment: The question fulfills the basic qualities of a question - it _shows an attempt_, shows what is wrong and has a clear purpose.

Comment: You can't just say: Yeah I am new to programming so let's go to an platform and ask every little question I have. Did you ever consider some self study? Find a book, get to know the basics.

Comment: I have the book: Objects first with BlueJ in Java sixth edition. The question was asked there. Anyway, sorry for asking lol

Comment: The Internet is most definitely a valid form of self-study, and as long as [there is a clear attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) I see no problem with this. The question was properly formulated. Now, [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057935/what-is-system-currenttimemillis) on the other hand...

Comment: If you didn't think the question was clear, and want to avoid the debate, probably should not have been so fast to answer